# Using file_get_contents or curl to embed html from a source outside my domain

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

We are developing a web app that enables the end user to place a bit of code on their webpage, so that anyone who visits their page will see a little pop up button on the edge of the browser window.  When clicked, it opens a small panel where they can enter a telephone number for the website owner to call them back.

I am running up against a security issue.  I am attempting to use server side include to place the button on the client's website.  However, because this included site is on a different domain than the client's website, it is not allowed.

I have tried these two methods that I got from online forums, neither of which worked for me.

1. Use the `file_get_contents` handler, like this;

   ```
   $includeFile =   
   file_get_contents("http://bizzocall.com/subdomains/dev/httpdocs/slideouttesttopDATA.php");
   echo $includeFile;
   ```

> ERROR failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found.

2. Use curl, like this:

   ```
   function curl($url){
       $ch = curl_init();
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
       $data = curl_exec($ch);
       curl_close($ch);
       return $data;
   }


       $feed = 'http://bizzocall.com/subdomains/dev/httpdocs/slideouttesttopDATA.php';
       $bizzobtn = curl($feed);
       echo $bizzobtn;
   ```

This didn't work either.

> ERROR  The requested URL /subdomains/dev/httpdocs/slideouttesttopDATA.php was not found on this server.

This looks like its truncating the bizzocall.com/ off of the url.  Perhaps If I knew how to write this chunk of code correctly,this would work.

Any help here would be welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 404 error is coming from the remote server, not your own. Try to reach that URL - You'll get the same 404.

When I visit http://bizzocall.com/subdomains/dev/httpdocs/slideouttesttopDATA.php, I get the following:

[image]

Therefore, the issue is that you're using the wrong URL. Your code is sound, however.

Comment: I see my error now.  I had the full path to the file instead of the alias (the subdomain) This was breaking it.  Beings you were the first to spot it, you ghet the point!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your curl code is working fine, the problem is the URL isn't found.
Put it in your browser to see.

If you own bizzocall.com, you'll want to put slideouttesttopDATA.php in a web accessible area, then you'll be able to access it with curl.

Answer (score 0):

Visit your link a browser and you'll see that the resource you're trying to request clearly doesn't exist. More info on the HTTP 404 status code found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it should be http://dev.bizzocall.com/slideouttesttopDATA.php as your URL does not work when pasted into a browser...